# My mobile is getting SLOW \ SLOWER

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, adjective-degrees

I have heard people say:

> My mobile is **getting slow.**
>
> My Mobile is **getting slower.**

Which is correct to say?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, but they mean slightly different things. In this context, the difference hardly matters.

> My mobile is getting slow.

Slow is being used as a simple adjective to describe the mobile phone. The phone is in the process of becoming (getting) slow.

> My mobile is getting slower.

Slower is a comparative form of 'slow'. **Slow, slower, slowest.** But what is the phone being compared with? The answer is that in your sentence there is an implied comparison taking place.

> My mobile is getting slower [*than it was in the past*].

The end result, *in this case* are two sentences which mean essentially the same thing. "My mobile is getting slow" states that it was not slow in the past. "My mobile is getting slower" is also saying the phone was not *so* slow in the past.

** Bonus content  **

If you *really* want to overthink it (and I don't recommend it), you can notice that the *first sentence* indicates that the phone was *not* slow in the past (it is *getting* slow, from a state of non-slowness). The second sentence only states that the phone is *slower than it used to be*. It does not rule out the possibility that the phone was always slow.

If you said:

> This was always a terrible mobile, and it's getting slower.

or

> This was a great mobile, but it's getting slower.

It would remove the ambiguity that potentially exists.

Answer (score 0):

Get means to reach a particular state or condition.
 It is usually used with adjective.

> to get angry.
>  to get bored.

My phone is getting slower implies that it is a continuous process and its speed is decreasing every moment. And I would prefer the second to the first.